# Does it matter what cereal I eat?

Tags: broken-age

I am being presented with a large array of cereals, does it matter which one I choose? I've clicked through at least 10 different options but keep just being presented with another?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not definitive, but I chose a number of random ones and it didn't seem to make a difference, same animation etc.  If you reject enough options, Mom goes "Nonsense!  You love [last one]!" and pours it anyway.

Comment: Probably just supposed to be symbolic of how tired Shay is of what little "choice" he has in his life.